# Python property returns constant

Tags: python, properties

I'm seeing code like this:

```
@property
def entity_class(self):
    return 'common'
```

As all that it does - it returns a constant value, I am thinking if I could replace it with this:

```
entity_class = 'common'
```

But I have small doubt that such change could break something. Will this change have some consequences apart from making `entity_class` writable? Why someone would need to disallow changes to attribute?

Comment: *"Why someone would need to disallow changes to attribute?"* - to prevent others from changing it? Python doesn't have real constants, so this is as close to it as you can get.

Answer (score 1):

You can safely replace the property with a class attribute, yes.

The only thing that would break is code that expects `ClassObject.entity_class` to return a `property` object rather than the constant value. Instance attribute access is unchanged.

Of course, you can now *set* that attribute on the instance, where with the `property` object you couldn't. Your code may break if someone does this, but so does code that would try and set `ClassObject.entity_class` (thus replacing the property object). For code with a good test suite, that should not really be a problem though.

Answer (score 1):

I wouldn't change it.

I've seen lots of bugs added by trivial changes such as this.

Yes, it might error either way if you try to set it in the future, but if you leave it a property it will error in a very understandable way. If you make it writable, it can be set in a way where the errors will appear in seemingly unrelated areas, making it much harder to track down.

Once you change it, it's also not clear that it is not intended to be changed.

If you want to change it, all you're doing is saving 2 lines of code.